# php/html Inserir varios dados com a mesma informação

Tags: php, html, formulário

Estou a precisar de uma ajuda pois estou um pouco bloqueado nessa questão.
Tenho um formulario onde coloco informação de um trabalhador.
Agora quero alterar essa página para poder inserir varios trabalhadores. No maximo até 16 trabalhadores.

Pagina1:

```
    <form method="post" action="inserir4.php"  name="dados-do-cliente" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <center><h1>Trabalhadores:</h1></center><br>
          <h3>Nome: <input type="text" name="Nome1">  Função: <input type="text" name="Funcao1"><span style="padding-left:150px">
            <Center><h1>Documentos  Trabalhadores : </h1></center>
    <div class="major"> 
     <h2><center> <b><p>Fichas de aptidão medica:</p> </h2>
     </b>  </center>
                <center>     <h3>          Data Validade: 
               <input type="date" name="MedicaValidade"> 
             Anexar Documento: <input type="file" name="MedicaAnexo"></h3></center>
        </div>
<center><button type="submit" style='width: 120px' value="enviar">Gravar</button>
    </center>
```

e agora quero arranjar uma forma de esse formulario ser repetido ate ao utilizador desejar.
E sempre que for um novo registo guardar no nome da variavel +1 
Exemplo página 2:

```
  <form method="post" action="inserir5.php"  name="dados-do-cliente" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <center><h1>Trabalhadores:</h1></center><br>
          <h3>Nome: <input type="text" name="Nome2">  Função: <input type="text" name="Funcao2"><span style="padding-left:150px">
            <Center><h1>Documentos  Trabalhadores : </h1></center>
    <div class="major"> 
     <h2><center> <b><p>Fichas de aptidão medica:</p> </h2>
     </b>  </center>
                <center>     <h3>          Data Validade: 
               <input type="date" name="MedicaValidade2"> 
             Anexar Documento: <input type="file" name="MedicaAnexo2"></h3></center>
        </div> 
  <center><button type="submit" style='width: 120px' value="enviar">Gravar</button>
    </center>
```

No final dos inserir coloquei esta opção:

```
if ($sqlinsert)
{
echo "<script>var r = confirm('Adicionar novo trabalhador?');" .
"if (r == true) {window.open('Trabalhadores3.html','_self','false');}" .
"else {window.open('Equipamentos.html','_self','false');}</script>";
 }
```

Se quiser mais um trabalhador clico sim e vou para a pagina seguinte se não quiser passo directamente para a ultima pagina. 
Mas estou com um grande problema pois quando passo directamente para a ultima pagina ele não vai buscar o inserirequipamentos mas vai buscar o inserir4 que é o de adicionar trabalhador4

Comment: Quer carregar novamente a página a cada novo formulário, ou que apareça na mesma página?

Comment: Aparecer a mesma pagina mas para guardar em sitios diferente. 
Como coloquei no exemplo

Comment: Pelo que percebo isto deve ser feito do lado do cliente. Têm alguma biblioteca como MooTools ou jQuery?

Comment: Estou a utilizar php/html/mysql Workbench . Estou a ver se há alguma solução assim de facil resolução.

Comment: Desculpa a minha insistência, mas acho que o que precisa não tem a ver com php/mysql. Você precisa ir buscar dados à base de dados para cada novo formulário? Ou precisa somente criar um novo formulário na página para o utilizador preencher?

Comment: Por exemplo o utilizador tem 3 trabalhadores e quer inserir os mesmos. eu quero que apareça o mesmo formulario para os 3 trabalhadores. A unica coisa que varia são os sitios que são guardados

Comment: É isto que você procura? __http://jsfiddle.net/KJLdB/__

Comment: Sim algo assim. Quando faço novo trabalhador aparecer numa nova pagina se não fica uma pagina muito mas muito extensa. 
Ter um botão guardar no final de cada pagina e depois perguntar novo utilizador?

Comment: Nos comentários em cima você escreveu "_Aparecer a mesma pagina mas para guardar em sitios diferente._". Mas você quer que grave o primeiro formulário e volte a carregar a página com novo formulário? Então isso sim pode ser feito do lado do servidor. Pode juntar o HTML completo, com a `<form>` também?

Comment: ja coloquei o form. No adicionar trabalhador1 aparecer nome1, funçaõ1, ficha de aptidao medica1 e no trabalhador2 nome2,função2, ficha de aptidão medica2

Comment: Sim voltar a carregar uma pagina com um novo formulario.

Comment: Existe forma mais facil do que criar 16 paginas de registo correcto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!

Você pode criar um loop em PHP para gerar os campos HTML do formulário, por exemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="inserir5.php"  name="dados-do-cliente" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php 
    $qtd = 16; //A quantidade de formulários
    for ($i=1; $i<=$qtd; $i++) {
?>
<center><h1>Trabalhadores:</h1></center><br>
<h3>Nome: <input type="text" name="Nome<?=$i?>"></h3>
<h3>Função: <input type="text" name="Funcao<?=$i?>"><span style="padding-left:150px"></h3>
<Center><h1>Documentos  Trabalhadores : </h1></center>
<div class="major" align="center"> 
   <h2>Fichas de aptidão medica:</h2>
   <h3>Data Validade: <input type="date" name="MedicaValidade<?=$i?>"></h3> 
   <h3>Anexar Documento: <input type="file" name="MedicaAnexo<?=$i?>"></h3>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
<center><button type="submit" style='width: 120px' value="enviar">Gravar</button></center>
</form>
```

Boa sorte.

Comment: Por exemplo se so quiser colocar 6 trabalhadores. 
Como posso colocar um botão para perguntar se quero mais utilizadores?

Comment: Bom, neste caso, seria melhor você utilizar AJAX, jQuery, ou algo do tipo. Vou ver se encontro um código que fiz para algo semelhante. Se encontrar eu posto para você.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, para resolver o problema proposto em seu comentário, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:
 1 - Primeiro, inclua na página do seu formulário, a versão mais nova da biblioteca jQuery.
 2 - O seu formulário, ficará da seguinte forma:

```
<form method="post" action="inserir5.php"  name="dados-do-cliente" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2"><h1>Trabalhadores:</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nome_1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Função: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="funcao_1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2"><h1>Documentos  Trabalhadores: </h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h2>Fichas de aptidão medica:</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data Validade: </td>
            <td><input type="date" name="MedicaValidade_1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Anexar Documento: </td>
            <td><input type="file" name="MedicaAnexo_1"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<p><input type="submit" style='width: 120px' value="Gravar"/></p>
<p><input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Adicionar"/></p>
</form>
```

O seu script JS para adicionar dinamicamente os elementos ficará assim:

```
var i = 1;
$('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    var table = '<br>';
    table +=     '<table>'
    table +=         '<tr>'
    table +=             '<td align="center" colspan="2"><h1>Trabalhadores:</h1></td>'
    table +=         '</tr>'
    table +=         '<tr>'
    table +=             '<td>Nome: </td>'
    table +=             '<td><input type="text" name="nome_'+i+'"/></td>'
    table +=         '</tr>'
    table +=         '<tr>'
    table +=             '<td>Função: </td>'
    table +=             '<td><input type="text" name="funcao_'+i+'"/></td>'
    table +=         '</tr>'
    table +=         '<tr>'
    table +=             '<td align="center" colspan="2"><h1>Documentos  Trabalhadores: </h1></td>'
    table +=         '</tr>'
    table +=         '<tr id="fichas_aptidao">'
    table +=             '<td colspan="2"><h2>Fichas de aptidão medica:</h2></td>'
    table +=         '</tr>'
    table +=         '<tr>'
    table +=             '<td>Data Validade: </td>'
    table +=             '<td><input type="date" name="MedicaValidade_'+i+'"/></td>'
    table +=         '</tr>'
    table +=         '<tr>'
    table +=             '<td>Anexar Documento: </td>'
    table +=             '<td><input type="file" name="MedicaAnexo_'+i+'"/></td>'
    table +=         '</tr>'
    table +=     '</table>'   
    $('#container').append(table);
})
```

Veja a execução desse código no link abaixo:
http://jsfiddle.net/RibeiroSt/Dn3MT/

Esta é uma solução bem simples, mas funcional para o que você precisa. É importante lembrar que será necessário um certo cuidado para tratar o recebimento desses dados do lado PHP.

Boa sorte.

Comment: e se eu criar as varias paginas não fica mais facil? estou a ter é um problema ao abrir as paginas e a guardar os dados

Comment: Alterei na pergunta uma das alterações que fiz

Comment: Se você vai inserir as mesmas informações, porém de pessoas diferentes, não seria melhor você ter uma única página PHP que processa os dados e um único formulário para incluir os dados do trabalhador? Seria o seguinte: Um script JS perguntaria se você deseja incluir um novo trabalhador. Se você escolher a opção 'Sim' ele iria chamar uma página PHP para salvar as informações do trabalhador que você inseriu e limpar o formulário para inserir os dados da próxima pessoa. Caso contrário, ele direcionaria para uma outra página, talvez para uma etapa posterior. É isso?

Comment: Exacto. Nao quero ter tudo numa unica pagina para nao tornar a pagina enorme

Comment: Ok. Vou pensar em algo assim e posto para você... hoje não vai dar porque estou muito atarefado, mas farei o mais rápido possível.